# Docker: how to set up file ownership in a data-only container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I've dockerized a PHP application using a data-only container. I used this ([docker-symfony](https://github.com/eko/docker-symfony)) containers stack.

This is a simple definition of a data-only container:

```
FROM debian:jessie
MAINTAINER Vincent Composieux <vincent.composieux@gmail.com>
VOLUME /var/www/symfony
```

Everything plays really well apart from ownership and permissions. I've noticed that when I mount volumes (my local directory) to the data-only container, the mounted files remain owned by my current user on the host, which in not recognized inside the container.

For example, If I'm starting the containers with `docker-compose up` as `ltarasiewicz`, and then I log into the data container, I can see that the mounted files have ownership set to:

`drwxrwxr-x  7 1000 1000 4096 Jun 10 21:27 symfony`

`uid` and `gid` of `1000` correspond to my host's user `uid` and `gid`. Because there is no such user inside the container, only IDs are displayed for the `symfony` directory. This makes it impossible to run the application.

So my question is how I can mount volumes to a data-only container and assign correct ownership to the mounted files, e.g. `root:www-data` or whatever other users I choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same image you use for running the application to make your data container. For example, if you want to make a postgresql database, use the postgres image for your data container:

```
$ docker run --name dc postgres echo "Data Container"
```

This command created the data container and exited - note that data containers aren't left running.

In the case of postgres, the volume ownership won't be set correctly until you use the volume to start a db:

```
$ docker run -d --volumes-from dc postgres
```

But other images will set up the ownership correctly in the Dockerfile.

Of course, if you just want to fix the permissions in a data container, just mount it and run chown:

```
$ docker run --volumes-from dc postgres chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: Hi Adrian. Thank you for this piece of advice. Reusing an existing `symfony/nginx` image for a data-only container helped. I noticed that the ownership problem was addressed by adding `RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data` to the nginx image Dockerfile. I think that this way a `uid` of 1000 (host user ID) would correspond to `www-data` inside the container. This way all files mounted as volumes inside a container made from `symfony/nginx` would be owned by `www-data`. However, I don't like the idea of starting a container and then running `chown`. I think there is too much redundancy.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that you've tied the image to your system - users who are not uid 1000 won't be able to use it. Again, take a look at what the redis and mongo official images do - they run chown in the entrypoint.sh at runtime.

Comment: Hmm, I think www-data is normally assigned UID 33 by the system. Probably a bad idea to change this.